# Hashed password causes FTP Upload problems

Tags: java, android, apache-commons, ftp-client, ftps

I have an Android Application which uploads data to an FTP(S) Server. Everything works fine until I hash my passwords. The strange thing is that login/upload and disconnect to the server seems to work, but my FTP shows no new data.

Heres the code where I fill my password:

```
MessageDigest sha;
    try {
        sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        byte[] hashOne = sha.digest(etPassword.getText().toString().getBytes());
        server.setPassword(hexEncode(hashOne));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        //
    }

static private String hexEncode(byte[] aInput) {
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    char[] digits = { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' };
    for (byte b : aInput) {
        result.append(digits[(b & 0xf0) >> 4]);
        result.append(digits[b & 0x0f]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

and in my Upload Service:

```
private void ftpUpload(File localSrc) {
    try {
        FTPSClient ftps = new FTPSClient();
        ftps.connect(server.getIp());
        ftps.login(server.getUser(), server.getPassword());
        ftps.changeWorkingDirectory(server.getRemoteDir());
        ftps.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        try {
            upload(localSrc, ftps); // does the upload magic
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // 
        } finally {
            ftps.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
}
```

For testing purposes I tried to use `FTPClient` instead, but I got the same problem.

Btw I use Apache commons-net for the FTP stuff.

I get no exception and everything seems to be working just fine. (`ftps.isConnected()`also says that I am connected). But no new data has been put to the FTP Server. Has anyone an idea what the problem could be?

**edit:** I'm not sure if I was clear in my initial post. I want the user to put in ip/username/password of an FTP(S) Server und later in the app some data should be uploaded to this server. Since I dont want to save the users password in plaintext in my database I wanted to hash it first. But since I hashed it before saving the password to the database I cant login to the FTP(S) Server, because of the wrong password.

So my problem is: How can I achieve a hashed password and still be able to login with it to the FTP(S) Server?

Comment: Do the various `ftps.` calls -- particularly the `login` one -- return error/status codes, and are you checking them?  If the login failed (perhaps for the reason Simon gave) then you would still be connected, but wouldn't be able to upload.

Comment: yeah, you were right, I forgot to check the return of `ftps.login(), but unfortunately I dont really know how I could hash my password on the server in my android app (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Well you hash passwords on server side not on client side.
You send password to FTP server server hash it and compare with hash in user database.

Comment: and how would I hash my password on the server? I now moved my hash method from the GUI class to my save method deeper down in my app. But that doesnt work unfortunately. `values.put(MySQLiteHelper.SERVER_PASSWORD, savePassword(server.getPassword())); cr.insert(ServerProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);` Thats the last possibility before I save the password in the database. Do you have an y idea how I could save it otherwise?